# Is there a way to make this CSS grid wrap correctly?

Tags: css, css-grid

I've been using media queries to make websites responsible for a while but I recently discovered CSS grids and I wanted to learn how to apply them.

My goal is to get the rows to wrap into a new one when the screen is smaller.

The problem is that the columns do shrink but don't wrap under when the screen is too small.

I've read some other posts about CSS-Grid and everybody is suggesting to use auto-fit minmax but it doesn't seem to work I'm not sure why.

Thank you very much

```css
/* Menu & Logo GRID Start */
.menu-logo-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr) );
    grid-template-rows: 100px;
    grid-gap: 3px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    grid-template-areas:
    "l l l l m m m m m m m m"
   
}
.menu-logo-grid > .menu {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    grid-area: m;
}

.menu-logo-grid > .logo {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    grid-area: l;
}
/* Menu & Logo GRID End */

/* Main Content GRID Start */
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr) );
    grid-template-rows: 300px 300px 300px;
    grid-gap: 3px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    grid-template-areas:
    "b b b b b b b b b b b b"
    "t t t t t t s s s s s s"
    "f f f f f f f f f f f f"
   
}

.grid-container > .bio {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    grid-area: b;
}

.grid-container > .things {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    grid-area: t;
}

.grid-container > .skills {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    grid-area: s;
}

.grid-container > .footer {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    grid-area: f;
}
/* Main Content GRID End */
```

```html
<html> 
  <head>
    <title>Title</title> 
    <link href="css/index.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="css/flexbox.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
 
  <body>  
  <div class="menu-logo-grid"> 
    <div class="logo">Logo</div> 
    <nav class='menu'>
      
        <a class='menu' href='#'>About Me</a>
        <a class='menu' href='#'>Contact</a>
        <a class='menu' href='#'>Projects</a>
      
    </nav>
  </div>
    
  <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="bio">1</div>
      <div class="things">2</div>
      <div class="skills">3</div>
      <div class="footer">Footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure you can do this when using template areas

Comment: If you are doing template areas you will also need to make a media query to define a new template for a different layout you want.

Comment: If you want elements to be more interactive here is a code pen I made awhile ago showing a bunch of differently applied flex-box elements: https://codepen.io/colinah/pen/dyXMmaP